# Select value select as keyboard button press

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html-select

I'm making a system where after blur a html select is appending and user need to select a option from that select box. But i need the selected value should be select automatically if user press same value key in his keyboard as if i press 2 the selected value should be 2.

```js
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  $(this).after("<select class=\"form-control\"><option value=\"Option\">option</option><option value=\"2\">2 </option><option value=\"3\">3 </option><option value=\"4\">4</option><option value=\"5\">5 </option><option value=\"6\">6 </option><option value=\"7\">7 </option><option value=\"8\">8 </option></select>");
  $('.form-control').on('change', function() {
    $('input').after('<span>' + $(this).val() + '</span>');
    $(this).hide();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. As per the snippet, its working as you wanted.

Comment: @ 31piy thank you for your response, it's working but i doesn't want to use mouse to select the value, just press same value key in keyboard it's should be automatically select that option and the value should append after the input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply setting the focus to the new select control like by giving the autofocus 
attribute to your select control should do the trick.

```js
$('input').on('blur',function(){
$(this).after("<select class=\"form-control\" tabindex=\"1\" autofocus><option value=\"Option\">option</option><option value=\"2\">2 </option><option value=\"3\">3 </option><option value=\"4\">4</option><option value=\"5\">5 </option><option value=\"6\">6 </option><option value=\"7\">7 </option><option value=\"8\">8 </option></select>");
$('.form-control').on('change',function(){
$('input').after('<span>'+$(this).val()+'</span>');
$(this).hide();
$('.text-control').val($('input').val() + $(this).val());
});
$('.form-control').focus();
})
```

```html
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" class="text-control">
```

Comment: thank you @tony mathew for response, but how to get selection value if i press same value key in my keyboard

Comment: @Codexx for me it works! I type something in the textbox, click somewhere else or press tab to cause the blur and the focus is on the new select then pressing 3 sets the value so in the select. Checked in Chrome and IE. Is it the text box that you want it set?

Comment: @Codexx I have updated the answer with the snippet if you want the textbox appended with the selected value

Comment: its working but i doesn't want the selected value append in input Thank you for your support..

Answer (score 0):

If the user only blur the input then you just show the select box

Then if there is some value in input it will be selected in the select box

I hope this help

```js
$('input').on('blur', function() {
  // check if the select is already present in the DOM
  if (!$(".form-control").length) {
    // get the input value
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    
    // we start the select form before the loop
    var form = "<select class=\"form-control\"><option value=\"Option\">option</option>";

    // we loop from 2 to 8
    for (i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
      // if the selected value from the input match with the value of the loop var then we selected it
      var selected = (i == inputVal ? " selected" : "");
      form += "<option value=\"" + i +"\"" + selected + ">" + i +" </option>";
    };

    // we the the closing tag for the select
    form += "</select>";
    
    // we inject the form after the input
    $(this).after(form);
  }
  
  $('input').on('change', function() {
    // the value change in input so we get it
    var newVal = $.trim($(this).val());
    // we remove all selected attribut of all option in select
    $(".form-control option").removeAttr('selected');
    // then we add the selected attribut to the right option
    $('.form-control option[value="'+ newVal +'"]').prop("selected","selected");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Instead of just writing code, it will help the readers if you explain why your code is solving the problem.